# django-cms Documentation: django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'polls' is not a registered namespace

Tags: python, django, documentation, django-cms

### Description

Using the tutorial found here: http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/introduction/05-apphooks.html. Up to step 5, there has not been any major issue. However, when completing the steps in step 5, the following error appears:

> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'polls' is not a registered namespace

Screenshot available here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJqzr.jpg.

This is after completing step `5.1.3 Restart the runserver`.

The site will only function correctly again if I go back and re-add polls to urls.py (which was removed in step 4!):

```py
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

    ### Huhhhhh? According to tutorial (#4), this line of code should be removed!!!
    url(r'^', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),

    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)
```

### Steps to reproduce

Followed tutorial up to step 5.1.3.

### Expected behaviour

Should not cause 500.

### Actual behaviour

Causes 500.

### Additional information

Any page with the following causes the 500 error to be raised:

`<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' instance.poll.id %}" method="post">`

However, I can also add back to urls.py the following, which partially fixes the error (maybe??), although I believe this is not the purpose of the documentation tutorial:

`url(r'^', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls"))`

But the site still experiences some 404s and 500s related to the Polls app. For example, in part 8 of the tutorial, the following error is raised when creating a new poll using the wizard (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncEe3.jpg).

Also have ran into a few other issues in part 4 and part 8 of tutorial.

In part 4, there is an `on_delete` error which is fixed by adding the following argument to `models.ForeignKey` function call:

`poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

Environment:

Python version: 3.7.6 (tutorial recommends 3.6)

Django version: 2.2.11

django CMS version: 3.7.1

Comment: Have you added app_name in your polls urls,py ?

Comment: @danish_wani Polls is installed via pip, per the step 3 of instructions (http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/introduction/03-integrating_applications.html), and thus polls urls.py is not in the project directory.